# How phpdoc declare return type is the caller?

Tags: php, phpdoc

For example:

```
class A {
    static function model () {
        $class = static::class;
        return new $class;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    var $var;
}
```

Can I tell editor the code `B::model()` returns type **B** that the caller rather than others?

I tried `@return self` is not work!

Comment: if you change static to public we can do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code :

```
class A {
    public function model () {
        $class = static::class;
        return new $class;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    /**
     * @return B
     */
    public function model(){
        return parent::model();
    }
    var $var;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
    /**
     * @return static
     */
    static function model () {
        $class = static::class;
        return new $class;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    var $var;
}
```

You can also try `@return $this`, it will work in PHPStorm, although semantically it should be used in non-static context only